# MS-Access 2007, Replace RegEx with data

Tags: regex, replace, ms-access-2007

I have a MS-Access 2007 file and a column, that I am trying to replace for the output, the column contains data like:

```
\\sad\images\Components\12\123_4.jpg
\\sad\images\Components\112\1125_3.jpg
```

My Query is

```
SELECT REPLACE(Path, "\\(\w*).(jpg)", "") AS FILENAME FROM Paths;
```

The regex identifies the and returns filename like \123_4.jpg, \1125_3.jpg, etc.

But when I run this query, the output has not changed, any help?

Comment: What do you mean the regexp returns filename but the output has not changed? You mean the data in table Paths has not changed? That is what you have expected?

Comment: My expected output is \123_4.jpg, \1125_4.jpg, etc, but I don't get it as expected. I am using an external tool to validate my regex and that works fine

Comment: I do not own Access 2007 so it is hard for me to say anything about the native support for regexp in queries. You may try to use a VBA script I have posted in http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5539141/microsoft-office-access-like-vs-regex-question/5539504#5539504 It will allow you to use a regexp in a query. In your case the code would be `SELECT my_regexp(Path, "\\(\w*).(jpg)") AS FILENAME FROM Paths;`. If you are not afraid of VBA, maybe you should give it a try.

Comment: If you want to update the underlying data, you have to use an UPDATE statement, not a SELECT. Also, your Replace() function used above is not the one in Access, as your arguments are in the wrong order, and it can't use RegEx.