# Matching similar/alike column entrys in MS Access 2003

Tags: sql, regex, ms-access

What I'm after is a summary of amount worked form base, using sql in MS Access, and this is what I want to do:

`Sum(IIf(([Time Report].Destination) Like 'D-[Time Report].[Baselocation]',0)) AS [Total WorkFromBase in P2]`

This doesn't work, as MS Access doesn't understand regex, and I need the 'D-' appended for it to match.

My options are as far as I'm aware:

1. Learn and use VB macro(?) to get the pattern matching correct
2. Use a complicated set of IIf statements, as sql doesn't have a native `else if` condition

I don't know VB, and I've only seen one [example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5539141/microsoft-office-access-like-vs-regex), which I couldn't make sense of.

If I go for a mass of IIfs then I have something like this

```
Sum(
    IIf(D-[Time Report].[Baselocation] = 'Base1', IIf(
        ([Time Report].Destination) = 'D-Base1',
    IIf(D-[Time Report].[Baselocation] = 'Base2', IIf(
        ([Time Report].Destination) = 'D-Base2',
    IIf(D-[Time Report].[Baselocation] = 'Base3a', IIf(
        ([Time Report].Destination) = 'D-Base3a' OR ([Time Report].Destination) = 'D-Base3b',
    IIf(D-[Time Report].[Baselocation] = 'Base3b', IIf(
        ([Time Report].Destination) = 'D-Base3a' OR ([Time Report].Destination) = 'D-Base3b',    ))
)) AS [Total Work From Base in P1],
```

Then I end up with a `Syntax Error (Missing operator)` type error,

So how can I match the two collumns, and sum when they're similar?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

*...  I need the 'D-' appended for it to match.*

You can concatenate "D-" to `[Baselocation]`, then use an equals rather than `Like` comparison.

```
[Time Report].Destination) = "D-" & [Time Report].[Baselocation]
```

But an `IIf()` expression includes 3 arguments.

```
IIf(expr, truepart, falsepart)
```

In your example, you supplied only 2 arguments, AFAICT.  I think you want the `Sum()` to include some value (`[amount worked]` ?) when `expr` is `True`, but zero when `expr` is `False`.  Maybe like this ...

```
Sum(IIf(([Time Report].Destination) = "D-" & [Time Report].[Baselocation], [amount worked, 0)) AS [Total WorkFromBase in P2]
```

Comment: This is wht I now have that works `Sum(IIf(([Time Report].Destination) = "D-" & [QRY7 Ready for Time Report].[Baselocation],[Time Report].[Hrs P1], 0)) AS [Total WorkFromBase in P1]` and `WHERE (([Time Report].Destination) = "D-" & [Time Report].[Baselocation])` after selecting so I don't get EveryThing with 'D-' in it. Otherwise. Perfect!

Answer (score 1):

Why not have a table of possibilities and reference that in your queries?

```
 If D-[Time Report].[Baselocation] = 'Base1' IN (SELECT Bases FROM NewTable)
```

Or

```
 SELECT D-[Time Report].[Baselocation], NewTable.Destination 
 FROM D-[Time Report] 
 INNER JOIN Newtable
 ON D-[Time Report].[Baselocation] = NewTable.Bases
```

Where NewTable contains a list of locations and a location that that base maps to.

You can also use the LIKE or ALIKE operator:

```
IIf(D-[Time Report].[Baselocation] LIKE '*Base1*'
```

Some references:

[Fundamental Microsoft Jet SQL for Access 2000](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa140011%28office.10%29.aspx)
[Intermediate Microsoft Jet SQL for Access 2000](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa140015%28office.10%29.aspx)
[Advanced Microsoft Jet SQL for Access 2000](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa139977%28office.10%29.aspx)

Comment: This seems like overkill, the new table is just a map of bases to locations, and are near enough the same except they have 'D-' prepended. Also I don't follow your variable names...table.Stuff? I've never used inner join before either, could you explain how you're using it please?

Comment: I have added a different possibility which may suit you better. If you intend to continue using SQL, you need to do a bit of reading. You could make that query a lot simpler. BTW table.Stuff is just a note to indicate any field selected from a table.