# How do I combine Right and Like functions in a query?

Tags: sql, ms-access

Given the following field and entries, how to I find the 3 entries that have a non-numeric character within the last 4 letters?

```
Field1
------
MA1234
DC4567
OHABCD
CAWXYZ
FLLMNO
MI9876
```

I'm guessing it would be a combination of `Right` and `Like "[A-Z]*"`, such as `Right([Field1], 4) = Like "[A-Z]*"` but that doesn't work.

EDIT: I'm looking for any entries where any of the last 4 characters is non-numeric.

Thanks!

Comment: sounds like regex and access do not play real well together. see this question for some more information - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5539141/microsoft-office-access-like-vs-regex

Comment: @HansUp, AB123C would satisfy the 'non-numeric within the last 4 letters' condition. I updated my original question to clarify. Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can grab the last four characters, and compare them one character at a time, like this:

```
WHERE RIGHT(Field1, 4) LIKE '[A-Z][A-Z][A-Z][A-Z]'
```

I know the example is in SQL 2008, but here's [a SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/5d420/1) that demonstrates it just as well.

**EDIT**:

If you want to the fields that have at least one non-numeric character (i.e. aren't all 0-9), you can search for a non-numeric value (`LIKE '*[^0-9]*'`) and make sure all four characters aren't numbers (`NOT LIKE '[0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9]'`) :

```
WHERE RIGHT(Field1, 4) LIKE '*[^0-9]*' AND 
    RIGHT(Field1, 4) NOT LIKE '[0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9]'
```

Comment: that worked .. I ended up using `WHERE RIGHT(Field1, 4) LIKE '[A-Z]'` which seems to look for only 1 of the 4 letters being within A-Z, which I didn't account for in my original question.

Comment: I'm confused, did you only want to find 1 letter in the last four, or the last four all had to be letters?  If the former, I would thinnk you would want `LIKE '*[A-Z]*'` (note the asterisks)

Comment: I didn't realize until just now that the data is invalid if only 1 of the last 4 characters is A-Z. I edited my original question, and my solution in the previous comment didn't work after all.

Comment: I think `Right([NABP],4) Like "*[A-Z]*"` is working .. adding the `*` before the range as well as the end

Answer (score 0):

Here is the answer:

```
SELECT *
FROM 
(
    VALUES
        ('MA1234'),
        ('DC4567'),
        ('OHABCD'),
        ('CAWXYZ'),
        ('FLLMNO'),
        ('MI9876')
) v(Code)
WHERE Code like '*[A-Z][A-Z][A-Z][A-Z]'
```