# Storing regex in MS Access DB kills functionality

Tags: regex, ms-access, join, ms-access-2007, vba

I have an MS Access DB along with a [function](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5539141/microsoft-office-access-like-vs-regex/5539504#5539504)  (thanks @MPękalski) which is called by a query in the join

```
create table OSS_File(
    id number,
    Kw text(255));

insert into OSS_File(ID,kw) values(1,"black or white");
insert into OSS_File(ID,kw) values(2,"green");
insert into OSS_File(ID,kw) values(3,"blue berry");
insert into OSS_File(ID,kw) values(4,"blueberry");
insert into OSS_File(ID,kw) values(5,"bluegreen");
insert into OSS_File(ID,kw) values(6,"yellow");

create table restricted_words(
    restricted_word text(255));    

insert into restricted_words(restricted_word) values("\bblack\b");
insert into restricted_words(restricted_word) values("^green$");
insert into restricted_words(restricted_word) values("^blue[ ]?berry$");
insert into restricted_words(restricted_word) values("yellow");

Function my_regexp(ByRef sIn As String, ByVal mypattern As String) As String
   Dim r As New RegExp
    Dim colMatches As MatchCollection
    With r
        .Pattern = mypattern
        .IgnoreCase = True
        .Global = False
        .MultiLine = False
        Set colMatches = .Execute(sIn)
    End With
    If colMatches.Count > 0 Then
        my_regexp = colMatches(0).Value
    Else
        my_regexp = ""
    End If
End Function

SELECT restricted_words.restricted_word, OSS_File.ID, OSS_File.kw
FROM restricted_words INNER JOIN OSS_File 
ON restricted_words.restricted_word=my_regexp(nz(OSS_File.kw),restricted_words.restricted_word);
```

I would have expected to get all but ID #5 back however I only get #6 back.
If however I remove the ^,$, or \b I rewrite the function like

```
.Pattern = "^" & mypattern & "$" 
or 
.Pattern = "\b" & mypattern & "\b"
```

I can get back results (except for "blue[ ]?berry" due to the [ ]?).

Why when the entire regular expression is stored in the table does the mach fail?

Comment: "\b" might be the backspace character. In general, you have to escape all escapes, or is Vba different? And what is the empty char class `[ ]` ?

Comment: Try inserting a `Msgbox mypattern` before the `with` block in order to double-check what it contains.

Comment: @sln [ ]? is a single non-required space to match both blueberry and blue berry (I don't write the specs I just have to program them :))

Comment: @sln \\bblack\\b isn't any better.

Comment: @BernardSaucier I used Debug.Print r.Pattern and it was correct

Comment: @Aba - Well if you mean to have backspace `"\b"`'s in the string, then "\\bblack\\b" isn't what you want.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As @HansUp pointed out both sides of my "ON" never matched so what I did is that if there was a match I returned the original sIn (OSS_File.kw)  string if not I returned "" (except if sIn was "" to begin with so I returned x) then I put OSS_File.kw on the left side of the on.

```
Function my_regexp(ByRef sIn As String, ByVal mypattern As String) As String
    Dim r As New RegExp
    Dim colMatches As MatchCollection
    With r
        .Pattern = mypattern
        .IgnoreCase = True
        .Global = False
        .MultiLine = False
        Set colMatches = .Execute(sIn)
    End With
    If colMatches.Count > 0 Then
        my_regexp = sIn
    ElseIf sIn = "" Then
        my_regexp = "x"
    Else
        my_regexp = ""
    End If
End Function

SELECT restricted_words.restricted_word, OSS_File.ID, OSS_File.kw
FROM restricted_words INNER JOIN OSS_File ON OSS_File.kw=my_regexp(nz(OSS_File.kw),restricted_words.restricted_word);
```

Thanks again everyone

Answer (score 3):

Your join's `ON` clause ...

```sql
ON
restricted_words.restricted_word
=
my_regexp(nz(OSS_File.kw),restricted_words.restricted_word);
```

`restricted_word` is a regular expression pattern such as `"^blue[ ]?berry$"`

On the right side of that join, you're asking for the function's return value, such as `"blue berry"`.

The *pattern* does not match the function's return value based on that pattern.

Consider a different approach.

```sql
FROM restricted_words AS r, OSS_File AS o
WHERE my_regexp_test(o.kw, r.restricted_word) = True
```

Here is that function tested in the Immediate window.

```vb
? my_regexp_test("blue berry", "^blue[ ]?berry$")
True
? my_regexp_test("blueberry", "^blue[ ]?berry$")
True
? my_regexp_test("strawberry", "^blue[ ]?berry$")
False

Function my_regexp_test(ByRef sIn As String,
        ByVal mypattern As String) As Boolean

   Dim r As New RegExp
   With r
        .pattern = mypattern
        .IgnoreCase = True
        .Global = False
        .Multiline = False
    End With
    my_regexp_test = r.Test(sIn)
End Function
```

Comment: SELECT DISTINCT o.ID, o.kw
FROM restricted_words as r, OSS_File as o
WHERE (((my_regexp_test(nz(o.kw),r.restricted_word))=True)); 
works as advertised.

However, I want which pattern flagged the keyword (kw)
SELECT r.restricted_word, o.ID, o.kw
FROM restricted_words r, OSS_File o
WHERE (((my_regexp(nz(o.kw),r.restricted_word))=True));
returns a Cartesian product so I need to keep working at it. 
Thanks for setting me on the right direction