# Regexp Access VBA - multiplier not working

Tags: regex, excel, vba, ms-access

I am trying to filter a table from Access using VBA DAO.Recordset. I want to match patterns like: `\w{3}\d{5}` ex: `ABC12345`

This works fine if I test only in VBA code (in excel) but when I execute the recordset no matches are found. The shorthand character classes `\w`,`\d` and multiplier part `{3}`  are ignored

Simple queries like: `select * from table where column like '*C123*'" or "'*[C123]*'` , work just fine.

I have found a solution but it is very ugly:
 `[A-Z][A-Z][A-Z][0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9]`

Comment: Does `[A-Z]{3}[0-9]{5}` work?

Comment: No, I tried and it does not work

Comment: `LIKE` does not support regex, only wildcards.

Comment: Maybe this answer can help you: http://stackoverflow.com/a/5539504/310276

Answer (score 1):

like 'xy' is not a (posix)regex, it's a sql-statement.
see Access SQL: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb208897(v=office.12).aspx
or maybe T-SQL https://msdn.microsoft.com/de-de/library/ms179859(v=sql.120).aspx
But the exact possibilities may depend on the connected database, and which engine is executing the statemenr.

Following query might work.

```
select * from table 
where customer like '[a-zA-Z][a-zA-Z][a-zA-Z][0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9]'
```

Regular expressions work quite different in each implementation.